# How to set/get a value in a two dimensional array list?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I want to set/get a vaule in a two dimentional arraylist.
like this,

```
    [0]   [1]   [2]
[0] true  false true
[1] true  true  true
[2] true  false false
[3] false true  true
```

my code 
:

```
 Arraylist<Arraylist<Boolean>> checkBoxState= new Arraylist<Arraylist<Boolean>();
```

get:

```
checkBoxState.get(position).get(h);
```

set :

```
checkBoxState.get(position).set(h,true);
```

- position, h are int variables

but my set/get codes are not working.
how to set/get checkBoxState(0.3)?

thank you.

Comment: What is the issue, you are facing?

Comment: how to get and add data in a two dimentional arraylist?

Comment: Have you added enough `ArrayList<Boolean>` to `checkBoxState`? And enough boolean values to the list you are trying to modify/get?

Comment: For every position of outer `ArrayList`, you need to create an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

Try This will work

```
        boolean test=true;
        ArrayList<Boolean> mBooleen=new ArrayList<>();
        mBooleen.add(test);
        heckBoxState.add(mBooleen);
        heckBoxState.get(0).set(0, false);
        heckBoxState.get(0).get(0);
        Log.d("your data", heckBoxState.get(0).get(0)+"");
```

Comment: consider commenting your code , not understandable by everyone

Comment: @TilakMadichetti ok

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
int rowCount = 4, columnCount = 3

private final boolean[][] selectedStatus;

 selectedStatus = new boolean[rowCount][];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            selectedStatus[i] = new boolean[columnCount];

            for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                selectedStatus[i][j] = false;
            }
        }


[0]   [1]   [2]
[0] false false false 
[1] false false false 
[2] true  false false
[3] false false false
```

Now initialize this by providing value of selected row column:

```
selectedStatus[0][0] = true;
```

which will be the initial. And get this in the same way by providing index

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are facing is populating the ArrayList, try this:

```
     ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> checkBoxState=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>>(); 
    ArrayList<Boolean> boolList=new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    boolList.add(true);
    boolList.add(true);
    boolList.add(false);
    checkBoxState.add(boolList);
    checkBoxState.add(boolList);
    checkBoxState.add(boolList);
    checkBoxState.get(0).get(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use nested ArrayList then you can try this out. I hope it helps, when you initialize the arrays you need to fill the inner too.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> checkBoxState = null;

    //filling the arrays you don't have to write boolean again in generics
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        checkBoxState= new ArrayList<>();
        checkBoxState.add(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    //You can fill the array how you want
    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxState.size(); i++) {
        checkBoxState.get(i).add(true);
    }
```